# Why Python Splitfolders is not working for spliting dataset into train and test folder?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I am trying to split a set of image (.bmp format) dataset into train and test folder using python ***split-folders***. I used the below code for this purpose. The code block is executed successfully without any error but does not split the image folder into the test and train folder.
My dataset is in "ZZ" folder, I want to split the dataset into the "Res" folder. I am using python 3.7.11 in the anaconda environment. How can I solve the problem. Help appreciate.

```
import os
import splitfolders
input_folder = "zz/"
output = "res" #where you want the split datasets saved. one will be created if none is set
# ratio of split are in order of train/val/test.
#You can change to whatever you want. For train/val sets only, you could do .75, .25 for example.
splitfolders.ratio(input_folder, output, seed=1337, ratio=(.75, .25))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only train and test folder
put zero in second part which represent validation

```
splitfolders.ratio(input_folder, output= output_folder, seed=1337, ratio = (0.75, 0, 0.25))
```